# Separating a single database into one user/transaction database and one time series database

Tags: database-design, time-series-database, multiple-database

My project involves storing sensor data (time series data) in db. There are about 5,000 sensors, each is sending data at 15 min to 1 hour interval. The existing service is using a single db, storing all frontend user, transaction and sensor data. The table holding time series data now has over 10 million rows. Other tables such as user table has a few thousands rows.

If separating sensor data into a dedicate db (say Postgres with TimescaleDB extension), will there be significant benefits in terms of performance, that out-weights the complexity introduced?

Comment: What exactly is the performance problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: And also: 10 million rows is nothing in todays terms, and nothing I would worry about, especially with a very low insertion rate (5000 inserts in a 15 min period). This is the sort of workload that can be handled easily by any modern hardware and database,

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Thanks for the comment.